# deferred.promise() in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I came across an interested Jquery method `deferred.promise()`. I long to know and try to understand about this new method what it mean and what is really does.
From short explanation and example ([Jquery Website](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/))

> The deferred.promise() method allows an asynchronous function to
>   prevent other code from interfering with the progress or status of its
>   internal request. The Promise exposes only the Deferred methods needed
>   to attach additional handlers or determine the state (then, done,
>   fail, always, pipe, progress, state and promise), but not ones that
>   change the state (resolve, reject, notify, resolveWith, rejectWith,
>   and notifyWith).

I went through it, but I'm not really quite understand about it. I thought that `.done()` method, one of `deferred.promise()` methods perform an action like this If I have `function A()` and `function B()`, `.done()` method determines what will happen after `function A()` completed like it start `function B()` after that, is it like this? Because I am looking for such a method like this, and hope `deferred.promse()` would perform such a function like this. Please kindly help clarify, Thanks.

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking. Try making the question more specific than "what does this do?"

Comment: @jegesh, i'm looking to understanding about `deferred.promise()`, please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to fire `functionB()` only after the promise of `functionA()` returns.  That is what should happen if you call `functionB()` in the `done()` method of `functionA()`.  But honestly, wouldn't it have been easier to just try it out yourself and see what happens?

Comment: @jegesh, absolutely. I'm looking for kind of jquery method that can perform such action, and I hope `deferred.promise()` is one of them because it contain event `.done()`.

Comment: Have you tried anything out on your own?